# RESTful service on emulator

Tags: web-services, rest, visual-studio-2017, tizen

I use RESTful service on Tizen emulator , this service works on android simulator but dose not work on Tizen emulator , How Can I test RESTful service on emulator in general? What are the possible issues for this problem ? I use visual studio 2017 Thanks

Comment: Are using Tizen Studio ? or Visual Studio for Tizen.NET ?

Comment: Give me some informations ... 
1. Which type of app are you developing ...Tizen Web, Tizen.NET ..

Comment: 2. As per my understand, you are trying to consume a REST service from your Tizen App.  but you can't consume it from emulator. And you can consume it from Android Simulator. That means RESTful Service is valid.

Comment: I use visual studio 2017 and Tizen.Net for developing Tizen mobile App. Yes, my REST service was good on android but not on Tizen emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Visual Studio for Tizen Development, i am assuming that you are developing **Tizen.NET** app.

You have go give internet privilege to allow the app to consume a web service. Add the privilege from `tizen-manifest.xml` **Privileges** section.

```
<manifest>
  .....
  .....
  <privileges>
     <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/internet</privilege>
  </privileges>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My issue was solved with your comment about add privilege.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tizen Studio, for security reasons, you need to give permissions to the url of your RESTful service. It's very simple, you need to add this line to your config.xml:

```
<tizen:metadata key="http://samsung.com/tv/metadata/use.preview" value="endpoint_URL=https://your.url"/>
```

Check too if you have this additional permissions in your Config.xml:

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
```

Please, try it

Comment: Thank you, please Mark an answer as ok